# Resize image by length with image magick

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize a image by its length, the width should remain. Is sounds quite easy, but somehow i don't get it. I'm using it together with PHP via the command line.

I'm using ImageMagick 6.7.3-9

By reading the docs, i would do the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/mogrify -resize x200! myimg.png
```

That gives me:

> mogrify: negative or zero image size `bbb.png' @ error/resize.c/ResizeImage/2570.

My goal is, that if bbb.png is w:400 h:400 i can resize it to w:400 h:200.

```
mogrify -resize x200 //Height with new width
mogrify -resize 200 //Width with new height
mogrify -resize 200! //New Width, old height
```

Can someone explain me, what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Also present on 6.7.3-1.  Seems like a bug since it works fine for width.

Answer (score 1):

Known broken, now fixed.  [Fix should be in ImageMagick-6.7.4-0 Beta available 2011-12-08.](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19964)

Answer (score -1):

I have not found your Image Geometry fromat `-resize x200!` in [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry). I think you should use

```
xheight
```

or

```
widthxheight!
```

I.e.: `-resize x200` or `-resize 400x200!`.

Comment: No, xheight calculates the width, I want to stretch it. Just resize the height. The doc says: ! forces the geometry i passed. Of course,  could first get the width and then do $width x200!. This works, but i realyl think there is a better way.